# Running nodejs app on Centos7 apache server

Tags: node.js, apache, meteor, cpanel, centos7

I'm trying to run a node web app (built with meteor) on a Centos7 server running EasyApache4 with WHM cPanel. I'm trying to run it on a subdomain off of one of our main websites on port 8080.

When going to the subdomain on port 8080, the connection just times out, but can see the html when using curl to access it.

Does anyone have any ideas why it won't work through the browser, and also how I can get it to look like it's running straight from the subdomain instead of having to go directly to the port.

**EDIT**

Below is the curl we are using to view the html

```
curl http://subdomain.site.com:8080
```

Doing that brings back the html no problems

Comment: Can you post the exact line you use with curl ( masking hostname and or any credentials of course)

Comment: Have a look at the network log in chrome to see what else it is fetching. Perhaps the loading of the body works, but all the subsequent fetches are failing, which would give you this behaviour. Is this port shared with other web sites? If so it won't work. Meteor needs to be on its own port. It can be setup to run with a reverse proxy if you do want to share a port

Comment: Nothing else comes into the network log. Nope the port isn't being shared - is there a port you would suggest? Thanks

Comment: Maybe the reason  for your curl work is you aren't sending any header, nor accepting redirects same way as your browser does. Try to look at headers sent from your browser in chrome devtools

Comment: Looking at the headers on the request, only Provisional headers are shown. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem today. I am using Memset Centos7 server with WHM/CPanel, running EasyApache 4.

After trying everything I could think of, I realised that I had a basic firewall setup, which closed all ports that were not listed. After adding port 8080, it worked.

Used this:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -i + -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

I am not 100% certain how secure this is, as I am still researching.